# Is there a way to do this with fast convolution?

Tags: fourier-analysis, convolution

If you could *please* offer any advice, this puzzle is driving me mad:

I've come across a problem that is trivial to compute in $\mathcal{O}(m^2)$ operations, but  which *very* closely resembles a convolution that could be performed in $\mathcal{O}(m\log(m))$ (using, for example, FFT). But I just can't seem to get it there.

Consider 3 vectors $N$, $R$, and $D$. The lengths of $N$ and $R$ are both $m$. The length of $D$ is $2m-1$.

Given two vectors $N$ and $D$, the result vector $R$ is defined as:
$R_i = \sum_j N_j ~D_{i+j}$. I want to compute the entire vector $R$.

Can you figure out a way to compute the vector $R$ in $m \log(m)$ time?

**Notes:**
It's apparent that each entry $R_i$ can be computed trivially in $\mathcal{O}(m)$, and thus the entire vector $R$ can be computed in $\mathcal{O}(m^2)$.

I've tried making this into a convolution or DTFT-like formula by applying a shift:
$Z\{R\} = \sum_j \sum_i N_j ~D_{i+j} ~z^{-i}$,

where $Z\{R\}$ is the Z-transform of $R$ (*i.e.* $R_i$ is the coefficient of $z^{-i}$ in $Z\{R\}$).

But I just can't seem to see it... I would be absolutely grateful for any help you can provide.

**EDIT: Example**
Let $N = [0.05,  0.93,  0.6 ,  1.  ,  0.6 ,  0.1]$, and
 $D = [ 1.  ,  0.5 ,  0.35,  0.7 ,  0.1 ,  0.03,  1.2 ,  0.6 ,  0.3 ,  5.  ,  0.45]$.

I believe the result should be:
$R = [0.4464 ,  0.70595,  1.5385 ,  0.3472 ,  0.60987,  2.8935]$

I computed it using the $m^2$ approach with python:

```
from numpy import *
def simplePropPosteriors(otherN,D):
    L = len(otherN)
    result = array([0.0]*L)
    for n1 in range(L):
        for n2 in range(L):
        result[n1] += D[n1+n2]*otherN[n2]
    return result
```

**Answer:**
Ah, as explained by @littleO:
Let $Q_i = N_{m-i}$; then R is found in the middle elements of the convolution $Q*D$.

Sincerely,
Oliver

Comment: I don't see how $R$ is not already a convolution.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 I'd be so happy if you could show me how to compute all of R in $m~log(m)$ (using FFT, iFFT, etc.).

Comment: Zeropad the inputs and the do the usual FFT --> Schur product --> IFFT --> trim. No? You might need to conjugate to account for the sum using $D_{i+j}$ rather than $D_{i-j}$, but you'll figure that out as you go I am sure.

Comment: Suppose you write $R_i = \sum_j N_{-j} D_{i - j}$ and let $Q_j = N_{-j}$. We see $R = Q * D$.

Comment: @Oliver Note that you can also compute $R$ directly using numpy.correlate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zeropad both $N$ and $D$ out to length $3M-2$. Then

Let $Q_i = N_{m-i}$ (the reverse of $N$).

$R$ is found in the middle of the convolution $Q*D$, which can be found in $m ~log(m)$ via ${DFT}^{-1}(DFT(Q) \cdot DFT(D))$.

Trimming the edges of $Q*D$ gives the correct answer for $R$.

Comment: +1 Brilliant-- I'm guessing this is equivalent to the comment from @littleO (where N is first reversed and then convolved with D), and then trimming the results of the (fast) convolution.

Comment: One question-- do you really want ${DFT}^{-1}(D)$ or is it $DFT(D)$?

Comment: $\operatorname{DFT}(f(-x)) = \operatorname{conj}(\operatorname{DFT}^{-1}(f(x)))$.

Comment: Reversing N as suggested by @littleO seems to work, but I can't reproduce the property you just quoted: using the vectors in the example, `conj(ifftn(array([0.0]*5+list(N2)+[0.0]*5),[16]))` does not equal `fftn(array([0.0]*5+list(N2[::-1])+[0.0]*5),[16])`. ?

Comment: @Oliver I am recalling from memory and might be wrong. If you can just flip the order of $D$ prior, then you can use the regular $\operatorname{DFT}$ rather than the inverse.

Comment: I'm going to edit your answer to do so and then accept. Thanks a lot for the help, I'll award a bounty as soon as stackexchange lets me. : )

Comment: @Oliver Ah. The property I was trying to recall flips the vector about its middle sample rather than reversing it.